# Switching terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1 doesn't work

Tags: shortcut-keys

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd>,<kbd>F3</kbd> ...) no longer switches to a different terminal like it used to in 10.04.  Is this the result of a change in some default setting? Is there a way to restore the old behavior?

Comment: I think that this did not change in 12.04 -- it works for me.

Comment: There is no change in settings in 12.04.

Comment: okay thanks I just tested with another system I have and it works there too.  I guess there is something messed up with my install where it's not working.

Comment: I can confirm this. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with a Ducky Shine 2 keyboard. It worked fine with my last keyboard (Logitech Illuminated Keyboard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue, and the fix was.. surprising? It turns out my keyboard was not compatible with 12.04 for some reason, swapping keyboards resolved the issue.

Comment: interesting that explains why on the other computer I tested did not have this problem.  I tested with another keyboard and it works fine, but unfortunately the keyboard that has the problem is my fancy mechanical keyboard so I don't want to swap keyboards. I might look at the problem more later and see if I can figure anything else out, but this is a really useful hint.

Comment: The keyboard I specifically have issues with is a "media" keyboard. it has all sorts of function keys for play, stop, pause, etc. its an extra so it floats around my systems. on my main desktop, I am using a fancy gaming keyboard, and it seems to work just fine, but it does have the same "media" keys.

Comment: Did you pressed the `Fn`, `Fn lock`, `F lock` or something like on the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have n-key rollover enabled on your mechanical keyboard, either by default or via a dip switch. I had the exact same issue (albeit with a KUL keybaord), and switching from n-key rollover to 6-key rollover fixed the issue.